# Reprojecting/converting an orthographic image/grid into a cartesian grid

Tags: trigonometry, image-processing

I'm trying to dewarp a fisheye image into a simple rectilinear image of a subset of the fisheye. As part of this, I'm trying to map the azimuth/altitude values into a point on the image.

[image: Grid image]

The points around each meridian line are equidistant so I can't use a squashed circle and simple angles from the centre point won't fit. The two axis are also linear (in this projection)

Using the law of cosines, I can calculate the radial angle out from the optical axis, but I can't figure out how to calculate the angle around the axis.

How can I convert from the azimuth/altitude values (e.g. -40,40) to a pixel location (e.g. 190,157)?

I've found some [similar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24054/converting-polar-equation-to-cartesian-coordinate-polar-equation-and-back-again) [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132671/converting-lat-long-coords-to-cartesian-x-y-then-calculating-shortest-distance) but I'm not sure they're the same and I don't understand the answers :)

Comment: I've figured out the radial angle from the optical axis, but still trying to figure out the angle around the axis.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477774/correcting-fisheye-distortion-programmatically